# CouchDB (nano) randomly returns `You are not allowed to access this db.`

Tags: node.js, express, couchdb, nano

I've integrated a user authentication and it already works very well. (Authenticates and returns a JWT in cookie.)
But for some reasons AFTER I logged in with my user and I want to establish a connection to the database I get a 403. The request itself isnt even protected. No verification if user is logged in or anything. Its a public request.

The funny part is, if I restart the node express application the exact same request goes through.

So it seems that anything within the process.

My login function:

```
const login = async (username, password) => {
  try {
    const response = await connection.auth(username, password)
    if (!response.ok) {
      return [401, null]
    }

    const token = jwt.sign({ sub: username }, secret, { expiresIn: '1h' })
    return [null, token]
  } catch (error) {
    return [error, null]
  }
}
```

This one gets called right after and I run into the catch block

```
  try {
    const conn = await nano('http://admin:password@127.0.0.1:5984')
    const db = await conn.use('test')
    […] 
  } catch (error) {
    // I LAND HERE
    console.error(error)
    return [error, null]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay I figured it out myself.

Looks like 403 was sent because it overrides your current session. What I did was basically authenticate again right after "login" was successful but this time I used `admin` and `password` again. Kinda ugly but it works.

```
    const response = await connection.auth(username, password)
    if (!response.ok) {
      return [401, null]
    }
    await connection.auth('admin', 'password') // < server credentials
```